# Extracting Data Based on Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, "SA" & "SB".

I am trying to extract the journal from "SA" to "SB".

I am trying with criteria in the code. (Later this will be based on criteria that the user chooses from a combobox.)

I would like the entire row (or better to the last column filled) from Sheet "SA" to be **copied** into Sheet "SB" if the value in Column B **OR** J is = "123456789".

In my code some rows are pasted on top the same row instead of the next.

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim SA As Worksheet
    Dim SB As Worksheet
    
    Set SA = Worksheets("SA")
    Set SB = Worksheets("SB")
    
    Dim DBSLRow As Long
    Dim ResultLRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    SALRow = SA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    SBLRow = SB.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Debug.Print SALRow
    Debug.Print SBLRow
    
    For i = 1 To SALRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "123456789" Or Cells(i, 10) = "123456789" Then
            SA.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
            SB.Cells(SBLRow, 1).PasteSpecial
            SBLRow = SBLRow + 1
        Else
           
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

I have read other questions and am unable to learn the mistake(s).
Perhaps there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

`For` loops automatically increment the iterator, you will skip rows if you do `i = i + 1` inside the loop.

I don't see where or why your code would be pasting on top of existing data, it doesn't do that for me, unless you have no data in Column A. You can however, just increment `SBLRow` instead of recalculating the last row each time (it will never go up by more than 1).

You should also use `Option Explicit` it will make your life a lot easier in the long run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim SA As Worksheet
Dim SB As Worksheet

Dim SALRow As Long 'Declare all your variables
Dim SBLRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set SA = Worksheets("SA")
Set SB = Worksheets("SB")

SALRow = SA.Cells(SA.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
SBLRow = SB.Cells(SB.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Debug.Print SALRow
Debug.Print SBLRow

With SA 'Good practice to always use explicit qualifiers
    For i = 1 To SALRow
        If .Cells(i, 2) = "123456789" Or .Cells(i, 10) = "123456789" Then
            .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy SB.Cells(SBLRow, 1)
            SBLRow = SBLRow + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Warcupine! Thank you for the answer!

As per option explicit, thank you very much for reminding me! I remember reading that it's kind of a must to avoid various unforeseen mishaps in the future.

Thank you for the note for the increment! That solved the skipping over issue! (Which I previously thought was writing over)

Answer (score 0):

for start you need to avoid type mismatch which didnt return error and use cells as property of worksheet

```
If SA.Cells(i, 2) = "123456789" Or SA.Cells(i, 10) = "123456789" Then
```

by taking 123456789 inside "" you said to program it is string type but u dont set property in Cells(i, 2). You can check .Value of this cell or .Text. if you dont chose property program will check by default property. alway use like below

```
 If SA.Cells(i, 2).Value = 123456789  ' to check value // number type of data /integer/long/double etc

 If SA.Cells(i, 2).Text= "123456789"  ' to check text string // text type of data / String
```

Best option is to declarate Variable and set value to like

```
 dim str_Text as String : str_Text = "123456789" 
 dim lng_Text as Long: lng_Text = 123456789
```

and then check condition

```
 If SA.Cells(i, 2).Text= str_Text 
 If SA.Cells(i, 2).Value= lng_Text
```

next

```
 SBLRow = SB.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

if You dont set last row like upper when i =1 u will paste items in occupied row.

and delete incrementation of i it will be incremented on next step. try below code

```
Sub test()

Dim SA As Worksheet
Dim SB As Worksheet
Dim str_Condition as String : str_Condition = "123456789"
Set SA = Worksheets("SA")
Set SB = Worksheets("SB")

SALRow = SA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
SBLRow = SB.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Debug.Print SALRow
Debug.Print SBLRow

For i = 1 To SALRow
    If SA.Cells(i, 2) = str_Condition  Or SA.Cells(i, 10) = str_Condition  Then
        SBLRow = SB.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        SA.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        SB.Cells(SBLRow, 1).PasteSpecial
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Tomasz! Thank you very much for the extensive explanation!

1. As per the number series, as they are supposed to be IDs, they are indeed stored as text and thank you!
Due to your pointers, I have ensured that the values are indeed stored as text (Cross-referenced with other posts).

2. Would you mind expanding more on the check condition?

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the note for deleting the increments!